# How to serve my localhost server that runs on my android to my android hotspot clients?

Tags: android, node.js, server, web

I have my android phone that runs a node.js server/website.
I wonder how can I provide this website to anyone that connects to my hotspot.

In addition would be nice that for any URL to redirect to myurl.com and then serve that local website to anyone that goes to myurl.com.

Comment: if your phone is running a server, then anyone can use just your phone's IP to access it. As for redirect - it is not possible without root.

Comment: `In addition would be nice that for any URL to redirect to myurl.com and then serve that local website to anyone that goes to myurl.com.` Pretty unclear what you want. Please elaborate.

Comment: `if your phone is running a server, then anyone can use just your phone's IP to access it.` ??? The phone acts as a hotspot. Only clients of that hotspot have a chance. If the phone was on mobile connection only then nobody. @Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: `I have my android phone that runs a node.js server/website. I wonder how can I provide this website to anyone that connects to my hotspot.` Every client device that connects and has a suitable client can reach your server. You dont have to do anything special for that.

Comment: @greenapps `???` - I assumed that it is obvious that I'm talking about devices connected to the hotspot.